# Hibernate :: Combine Column values

Tags: hibernate

how to combine column values on hibernate?
for example:

```
City
-------
texas
california
new york
newark
```

Result:

```
City
-------
texas,clifornia,new york,newark
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum; answers are expected to be answers, not pleas for help.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7705302/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Formula`. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/)  in the section of formula you can see examples.